# simple wall post

Tags: jquery, database, post, facebook-wall

I'm working on a simple wall post and having a hard time trouble-shooting it. I'd like it to post without having to reload the page (like a facebook post). Nothing really happens when I hit submit. The page reloads, no post appears, and nothing is inserted into the database. I can't figure out why. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form id="submit_wall"&gt;
<label for="message_wall">Share your message on the Wall</label>
<input type="text" id="message_wall" />
<button type="submit">Post to wall</button>
</form>
<ul id="wall">
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form#submit_wall").submit(function() {

var message_wall = $('#message_wall').attr('value');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "insert.php",
data:"message_wall="+ message_wall,
success: function(){
$("ul#wall").prepend("<li style="display: none;">"+message_wall+"</li>");
$("ul#wall li:first").fadeIn();
}
});
return false;
});
});
</script>
</body>
```

insert.php is just a simple db input:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message_wall'])){
/* Connection to Database */
$link = mysql_connect($host, $un, $pw) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
@mysql_select_db($db, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

/* Remove HTML tag to prevent query injection */
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message_wall']);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO wall ("message") VALUES( "'.$message.'")';
mysql_query($sql);
echo $message;
} else { echo '0'; }
?>
```

Comment: what is the trouble? what is happening when you try this? please explain present result and what you are tying to achieve.

Comment: I don’t see any thematically connection to Facebook here.

Comment: just wanting it to post without having to reload the page (like a facebook post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is quite not a question. But I something i'd like to point out is that you should use

```
var message_wall = $('#message_wall').val();
```

Instead of

```
var message_wall = $('#message_wall').attr('value');
```

Other than that, I dont see anything that could be wrong. Please explain yourself a little bit better

Here's the "wall post" part. You have to add the ajax call of course

http://jsfiddle.net/myuX3/

EDIT:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data:{'message_wall':message_wall}, /* This is the line i've modified */
    success: function(){
        $("ul#wall").prepend("<li style="display: none;">"+message_wall+"</li>");
        $("ul#wall li:first").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: great point with the change. thank you. 

I am sorry for not being more clear. I updated it so it is more of a question.

Comment: Added a jsfiddle for you, changed the html a little bit to make things easier. Of course, I didn't add the ajax part (bc I think it's okay)

Comment: Nicolás, quick update. The script you provided is working really well, but I can't get the AJAX to input any data into the database. I've looked over it multiple times and can't find an error. Do you see anything wrong? (I posted the script below)

Comment: Modified your ajax call. Let me know if it works. EDIT. BTW, have you checked that $_POST['message_wall'] actually exists?

Answer (score 1):

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<label for="message_wall">Share your message on the Wall</label>
<form name="post" id="post" name="post">
<input type="text" id="message_wall" name="message_wall"/>
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Post to wall"/>
</form>
<ul id="wall">
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submitbtn').click(function() {

    var message_wall = $('#message_wall').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data:"message_wall="+ message_wall,
        success: function(){      
            var $d=$("<li>"+message_wall+"</li>").fadeIn(500,function() {
                document.post.reset(); 
            });
            $("ul#wall").prepend($d);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});

</script>
```

insert.php:
(Name, password, and database are all correct. I have triple-checked them)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message_wall'])){
/* Connection to Database */
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "******", "******") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
@mysql_select_db("*******", $link) or die("Couldn't select database");

/* Remove HTML tag to prevent query injection */
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message_wall']);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO wall ("message") VALUES( "'.$message.'")';
mysql_query($sql);
echo $message;
} else { echo 'fail'; }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="message_wall" name='message_wall' /> // you can use "name" attribute and "serialize()" method
```

js:

```
data: $(this).serialize(); 
success: function(data){ // pass the data to your success callback
$("ul#wall").prepend("<li style='display: none;'>"+data+"</li>"); // correct the quotation marks
```